# Efficient way of aligning multiple irregular time series in a regular time series with multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I am new to python and aim to align multiple irregular time series into one regular object. I have tried this naive implementation for just one time series, where `dts` is a regular datetime array (including timezone), `mydates` contains the irregular dates (similar type) and `myts` stores irregular data values:

```
    regts = [None] * len(dts)
    for j in range(len(mydates)):
        idx = dts.index(mydates[j])
        regts[idx] = myts[j]
```

The speed is aceptable for up to a length of 1000 but then it becomes very slow due to the size of the dataset. I am sure there are much efficient ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

A `dts.index()` that does a linear scan is going to yield quadratic badness, painful for lengths much more than a thousand. It's a loop nested within your outer loop.

Produce lots of tuples with a list comprehension covering your source data, then sort it to produce the required time series.

So if

```
for stamp, value in mytimeseries:
    print(stamp, value)
```

displays your combined time series, then `sorted(mytimeseries)` is the desired result.